# angular table header widths dont line up after making the header a component

Tags: angular8, angular-components

So this is a basic table

```html
<table class="table table-striped">

    <thead>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>
            <th scope="col">State</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of Array">
            <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.state }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But when I take the header and put it into a component the widths of the headers dont match the width of the table columns

```html
<table class="table table-striped">

    <thead>
        <app-tableheader></app-tableheader>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of Array">
            <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.state }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is the component now with the same html

```html
<tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">City</th>
    <th scope="col">State</th>
</tr>
```

So I dont quite understand what I'm missing here.   New to componetizing angular.